# base64 photo and paperclip -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, base64

I want to handle a base64 photo with paperclip. 
When I try:

```
photo = Photo.new 
string = base64string

photo.photo = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(string))
photo.save
```

It does not work.
Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that the StringIO you are using is the paperclip opened one. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/upfile.rb

```
 sio = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(string))
 puts sio.respond_to?(:original_filename)
 puts sio.respond_to?(:content_type)
```

It needs to have those methods in order to have paperclip work with StringIO.  Make sure it is setting them.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, and the github link provided is broken.  Any updates?

Comment: The issue is that paperclip opened and added methods to the Ruby core class StringIO and expects that the StringIO you are using has them.  That is what the respond_to? calls are determining.  I am not sure this is true anymore or where they moved paperclip git to.  You may want to find that.