# Rails3 - Problem saving base64 image with paperclip?

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, base64, attachment

This is similar to the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641728/base64-photo-and-paperclip-rails), but that solution doesn't work for me.  Maybe it's because I'm not passing the data in correctly.

I'm pulling screenshots from Flash and displaying them on the page using Jquery:

```
   $SNAPSHOT_PREVIEW.attr("src","data:image/jpg;base64," + imgData);
   $HIDDEN_BASE64_STRING.val(imgData);
```

I had it nice and working where you could save the image to Rails in Flash, but Flash won't allow you invoke a post action without the user pressing a button for security reasons.  Makes sense.  Anyway, now I can't get Paperclip to save the image coming from the HTML form:

```
#(photo has_attached_file:image)
@photo = params[:photo]
data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:base64_string]))
data.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
data.original_filename = "screenshots.jpg"
data.content_type = "image/jpg"
@photo.image = data
```

Yields the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `image=' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x8c2e420>):
```

How do I need to finesse the base64 image data into a paperclip attachment?

For bonus points, do I need the hidden field to pass the data or is there a clever, browser compatible way to use the image src as a form value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the code:

```
@photo = params[:photo]
```

`params` is just a hash, so later, when you call `@photo.image`, Rails bugs out. Perhaps you want:

```
@photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
```

instead?

Comment: Wow.  It's been a long day.  Thanks for being the extra pair of eyes.