# base64 decoding by paperclip in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, base64

I am developing a server backend for my iphone application. I need to upload a picture from my Iphone app to the rails server

I have a base64 encoded image in the post request from my app which I need to parse and send to the Paperclip plugin for the re-sizing of the image.So can anybody suggest me how to do it.

Help me!!!. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to save image with correct extension you have to specify content type. 
It's quite nice to have this in your model as method which is called `before_validation`

```
   StringIO.open(Base64.decode64(self.photo_base64)) do |data|
      data.original_filename = "image_name.jpg"
      data.content_type = "image/jpeg"
      self.photo = data
    end
```

Comment: You should clarify that photo_base64 is not the the URI but rather the  '<data>' value within the URI string. Therefore, you need to discard the 'MIME-type' and 'encoding' if it does include these (ie., `photo_base64 .split(',').pop`)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`sio = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(string))`

[ source: [base64 photo and paperclip -Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641728/base64-photo-and-paperclip-rails/4652604#comment-8459269) ]