# Carrierwave + File Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, file-upload

I'm trying to figure out how to properly setup [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) to be able to handle a file being sent via [File Uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader).

### File Uploader

I've attached `fileuploader.js` and `fileuploader.css` to my asset pipeline (rails 3.2.0) and have the following html:

```
<div id="file-uploader">       
    <noscript>          
        <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
        <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
    </noscript>         
</div>
```

And javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
      // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
      element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
      // path to server-side upload script
      action: '/photos',
      debug: true,
      params: {
        authenticity_token: "<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>"
      },
      onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
        alert(responseJSON.toString());
      }
    });
});
```

When I select a file it kicks off the script and my application gets called. That is what I don't know how to handle.

### Carrierwave

I have a `Photo` model which has `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader`. Therefore in `PhotoController` I have:

```
def create
  io = AppSpecificStringIO.new(request.raw_post,params[:qqfile])

  @photo = Photo.new(:image => io)

  if @photo.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  { render :josn => @photo.to_json(:methods => :success, :only => [:id, :image]) }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  { render :josn => {:success=>false} }
    end
  end
end
```

The param only has `qqfile` which is the file name. I found out that `request.raw_post` has the data for the image. But I don't know what format it is (is it 64Bit or not). I've been trying to find any resource I could on the subject and trying out anything. One [source](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Upload-from-a-string-in-Rails-3) on Carrierwave's wiki suggested to use a AppSpecificStringIO class.

```
class AppSpecificStringIO < StringIO
  attr_accessor :filepath

  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args[1..-1])
    @filepath = args[0]
  end

  def original_filename
    File.basename(filepath)
  end
end
```

On File Uploader's wiki there is a [suggestion](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/wiki/Rails-%2B-CarrierWave) for CarrierWave, but I can't figure anything out there either. `CarrierwaveStringIO` doesn't exist as far as I can see.

I just want to get an ajax solution to uploading images to Carrierwave. Thank you to anyone who can help me.

#### Other links for reference:

- [base64 image with Carrierwave - SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622404/use-base64-image-with-carrierwave)
- [File uploader's notes on server side info](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/tree/master/server) - looks like I need to handle two ways to get the file.

Comment: can you please share how you used uploadify for this?

Comment: Here is what I ended up doing for the uploadify part. It is a little out of context so I'm not sure how much it will help. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/9796b4ecfc567864cc9d)

Comment: thanks Ryan, I hope flash is not giving any problems with rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the [rack-raw-upload](https://github.com/newbamboo/rack-raw-upload) gem

and then in my controller i am doing the following:

```
def create
  if params[:qqfile]
    ## IE acts differently 
    file = params[:qqfile].is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile) ? params[:qqfile] : params[:file]
    @attachment.asset = file
    xhr_create
  else
    super
  end
end

def xhr_create
  if @attachment.save
    render :json => { success: true }
  else
    render :json => @attachment.errors.to_json
  end
end
```

and in application.rb

```
 config.middleware.use 'Rack::RawUpload', :paths => ['/attachments']
```

[Here is a nice writeup](http://marc-bowes.com/2011/08/17/drag-n-drop-upload.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up going with Uploadify.