# Upload file with api and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, carrierwave

I'm writting api for webservice, and i need to provide ability for users to upload files using this api.

For my uploads i'm using carrierwave, but not sure how do i pass file from api request to carrierwave, and how the file should be sent from client machine to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is based on the tool which is used by the API consumer. If API consumer is using ruby then can consume it by passing File object, or using httmultiparty gem we can upload the file.

For you reference https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty. Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: SO, there is no universal tool for all kind of consumers?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I implement file uploads over a REST API by allowing clients to send a PUT request with the base64 encoded binary data of the file inside the request body.

Then you can route the client request to your CarrierWave uploader, which can decode the binary data contained in the request body using something like `FilelessIO.new(Base64.decode64(encoded_file))`

Comment: Also, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854916/base64-upload-from-android-java-to-ror-carrierwave

Comment: Does this stands still if we're not talking about image files? Say a pdf or a .docx file. Does base64 encoding of a such files is still possible?

Comment: @Sebastialonso yes, you should be able to base64 a PDF or DOCX file as well

Answer (score 0):

Try [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client). It encapsulates net/http with cool features like multipart form data:

```
require 'rest_client'
RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000/foo', 
  :name_of_file_param => File.new('/path/to/file'))
```

It also supports streaming.

`gem install rest-client` will get you started.